# How to open a new browser window with the navigation bar enabled?

Tags: javascript

I have this JS method:

```
function OpenLink(strDestination)
{
    var features = ['left=10',
                    'top=10',
                    'location=0',
                    'menubar=0',
                    'resizable=0',
                    'scrollbars=1',
                    'status=0',
                    'titlebar=0',
                    'toolbar=0',
                    'width=' + (GetWinDimensions().Width - 500),
                    'height=' + (GetWinDimensions().Height - 150)];

    window.open(strDestination, "a", features.join(','));
}
```

Which opens a new browser window that does not have the address bar, navigation bar, or any other 'features'.

I have reviewed the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) pertinent to `window.open`. It says Internet Explorer and Firefox support the `toolbar` feature however it only worked in Firefox for me. The popup did not include the navigation buttons in IE, and as expected Chrome didn't either.

If I set all of these features to `1`, then it was just opening a new tab. I tried changing the `"a"` string to `"_blank"` but it still opened a new tab rather than a new window.

How can I open a new window which also has the navigation bar enabled?

Comment: have you tried removing all the options?

Comment: @DanielA.White If I call `window.open(strDestination, "a");` it opens a new tab. Same with `"_blank"`.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
function OpenLink(strDestination)
{
   var features = ['left=10',
                'top=10',
                'location=0',
                'menubar=0',
                'resizable=0',
                'scrollbars=1',
                'status=0',
                'titlebar=0',
                'toolbar=0',
                'width=' + window.innerWidth - 500,
                'height=' + window.innerHeight - 150];

   window.open(strDestination, "a", features.join(','));
}
```

Comment: This does not include the navigation menu in Chrome. Also you have extra `)` on your `width` and `height` values

Comment: I removed the `)` , And have no idea about chrome.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! :) What is the purpose of "a"?

Comment: @balazs630 Thanks. "a" is an optional name for window that specifies the target attribute or the name of the window. To better understanding please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438304/what-is-name-parameter-in-window-open

Comment: The problem is it doesn't seem Chrome can open a new set-size browser window *and* also include the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

**This simple code open a new window with navigation enabled and with 200 width , 100 height:**

```
function myFunction() {
     var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
}
```

Comment: This also does not include the navigation menu in Chrome.

Comment: @sab669 what if you open a new tab instead of window?

Comment: It's strongly preferred that we open up a window as our users aren't typically "tech savy". Don't want to risk them closing the browser window (and therefore both tabs) when they mean to only close this popup.

Comment: i didn't understand you first with browser navigation, then i found out what do you mean, so i will share if i find your solution ♥

Comment: The problem is it doesn't seem Chrome can open a new set-size browser window *and* also include the navigation.

Answer (score -1):

You know and should know that mobile devices support new tab of different kinds and rarely windows at all if it is not available in progressive  app technology like [A2HS](https://duckduckgo.com/A2HS)
Adding event  handlers to the window would solve the desktop problems with exiting .
Just choose the right opening options. Thanks!