# Open a new window with navigation arrows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm launching a new window with the navigation bar but here it's loading without navigation bar or arrow.

Would anyone know how to load the new window with the navigation arrow?

```js
window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank",
"toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

Comment: RTM:
 ["location,toolbar,menubar,scrollbars,resizable,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: [Possible duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812505/how-to-open-a-new-browser-window-with-the-navigation-bar-enabled

Comment: just do `window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank")`  It looks like as soon as you specify a width / height in Chrome it will act like a simple window only.

Comment: I assume you are using Chrome as otherwise you would have no issue, Chrome is **Special** - See Possible duplicate of [How to window.open with a toolbar in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Add additional window features param `location` to `window.open` options like:

```
window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank","location,toolbar,scrollbars,resizable,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

Comment: In Chrome, no navigation controls.

Comment: Snippets don't work and using `window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank","location,toolbar,scrollbars,resizable,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");` doesn't show the toolbar in Chrome. I think OP need to specify Browser as Chrome has some specific restrictions as far as I know.

Comment: The location makes no difference, it's a restriction in Chrome, nothing much can be done about it, apart from don't use the `specs` parameter.  Just `target=_blank`.